# Small display problems of the select HTML

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms, angular-template

I'm on Angular, I created a form. And when I arrive on the page the select works but nothing is displayed.

```
<select formControlName="breed" required>
    <option value="undefined" selected="true">{{ 'pet.choose_breed' | translate }}</option>
 </select>
```

**The result is as follows**:

[image]

**I would like it to give this**:

[image]

The problem probably comes from the value, I modified it several times but nothing works.

Comment: what is not working in this do you want to display a drop down based on the select of the previous select option

Comment: In fact I would just like that at the moment I arrive on the page that it is displayed "choisir une race" on the select. Sorry, I don't know if I'm clear enough :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at `[selected]` attribute or `[(ngModel)]` to give a default value to your select dropdown.

This medium link might help you understand better https://medium.com/@phismonster/set-default-value-for-select-in-angular-2-27f0da413935

Comment: For those who have the same problem the first part of this article gives us the answer. It's all really silly. :) Thanks to @Rahul Singh

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want a placeholder to be displayed on the select element.

```
<select placeholder="choisir une race" formControlName="breed" required>
    <option value="undefined" selected="true">{{ 'pet.choose_breed' | translate }}</option>
    <option [value]="breed.id" *ngFor="let breed of breeds">{{ breed.lib }}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Yes, actually I want it to display a sentence by default when the user arrives on the page.

Comment: Is it working the code i gave you? i think you just need to add that placeholder="choisir une race" on the select element.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. But under angular I have a lot of similar problems